# Scroll Down Issue Using List Control in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services

I am using List Control in SSRS 2008. The List has one level grouping and have 2 tables within the list.
As you can see in the screen shot #2. The report works perfectly ok but whenever i scroll down the page looks so mashed. You can see the screen shot #3.

Please check screen shot #1,#2,#3

Thanks in advance.[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Hi maybe you checked this options in List Propertys "Repeat header row on each page" or "Keep header visible while Scrolling"

Comment: na i didn't ... this is something else